# HPACUCLI Remotely make active spare permanent member

Tags: hp-proliant, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

We have an old HP server - we let the HPE contract expire as it'll be decom'd soon, and our monitoring has flagged a failed disk.

For various reasons it's difficult to organise access to the server, so ideally we'd like to remove the Failed disk (ie. disassociate it from the array), and promote either spare to replace it and have it rebuild on one of them so we can just leave it until it's time to remove it with all the other gear in the DC.

Now, from what the internet has said - the way is to remove the inactive spare from the array, and then physically yank it out and replace the failed drive with it (which invokes a rebuild on that disk) - but I'm looking for **a remote solution** (if one exists / or confirmation that the above physiucal swap is the only way).

```
=> ctrl slot=0 show config

Smart Array P410i in Slot 0 (Embedded)    (sn: 5001438014F530C0)

array A (SAS, Unused Space: 0  MB)


  logicaldrive 1 (683.5 GB, RAID 5, OK)

  physicaldrive 1I:1:1 (port 1I:box 1:bay 1, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:2 (port 1I:box 1:bay 2, SAS, 146 GB, Failed)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:3 (port 1I:box 1:bay 3, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:1:4 (port 1I:box 1:bay 4, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:1:5 (port 2I:box 1:bay 5, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:1:6 (port 2I:box 1:bay 6, SAS, 146 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:1:7 (port 2I:box 1:bay 7, SAS, 146 GB, OK, active spare)
  physicaldrive 2I:1:8 (port 2I:box 1:bay 8, SAS, 146 GB, OK, spare)
```

SEP (Vendor ID PMCSIERA, Model  SRC 8x6G) 250 (WWID: 5001438014F530CF)

Answer (score 0):

```
hpacucli ctrl slot=0 array A remove drives=1:2
```

Then add your spare **not** your active spare.

```
ctrl slot=0 logicaldrive 1 add drives=2I:1:8
```

Give that a go.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but fails at the first command citing the array is degraded.

Comment: Try reverse the commands in that case. Add the new and let it rebuild, then try remove the old. That way, even if add works but the remove doesn't... whilst not ideal at least you have a redundant raid.